# how to reset text area after pressing button using angular js?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am working on a project where i have to perform actions like social media, i stuck on a stage where i have to comment and then i have to reset that editable div. 
Editable Div code:

```
<div id="txtComment"  contenteditable="true" class="form-control txtComment" style="height: 156px;  margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

My button for calling comment function Code:

```
<input  type="button"   value="POST" ng-click="comment(<?php echo $itemId ?>,<?php echo $itemDesc ?>  ,user_comment,0,0,mood)">
```

my function:

```
$scope.comment=function (itemid, itemdescid,user_comment,replyId,parentcomId,mood)
    {
        var feeling="";
        //console.log(mood);
        if (typeof mood !== "undefined") 
        {
            feeling=mood;

            //console.log(mood+"test");
        }
        var comm="";

        if(replyId==0)
        {
          comm=$("#txtComment").html();
        }else if(replyId == parentcomId)
        {
            comm=$("#"+parentcomId+"comment").html();

            //console.log(comm);
        } else
        {
            comm=$("#"+replyId+"comment").html();
        }

        console.log(comm);

        //console.log(feeling);

        var req = {
            method:"POST",
            data:{item_Id:itemid, item_desId:itemdescid, comment:comm,commentReplyId:replyId,parent_commentId:parentcomId,User_feeling:feeling,userId:$scope.id},
            url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/ItemImportance/Comment",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

        };
        $http(req).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data !=null)
            {
                if(response.data.msg !=null)
                {
                    alert(response.data.msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    //var scopeNmae="item"+"_"+itemid+"_"+itemdescid;
                    // console.log(scopeNmae);
                    //$scope[scopeNmae]=response.data;

                   //console.log(response.data);

                // window.location.reload();
                   $scope.itemcomments=response.data;
                   //eraseText();
                }
            } else
            {

            }
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        });

    }
```

what i have to do is just empty my editable div after i click on comment button!
please help me as fast as you can.

Comment: I would use a textarea instead of a div. Then add a ng-model to it (ng-model="comment"). And on click just clear the angular model ($scope.comment = '').

Comment: Otherwise just clear the content of the div: $("#"+replyId+"comment").html('')

Comment: not working for me still same

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a really simple example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsyzPMEJeR2qKnKhGuDu?p=preview), please have a look at it.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="comment" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="comment = ''">Clear</button>   
</body>
```

My recommendations are:

- Keep it simple
- Don't try to mix Angular with jQuery, unless you **really** have to
- Use appropriate html elements

Edit:

Example [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q5zFd4QqD0HE8d5aGcep?p=preview) with content editable div. It's a fork from the [AngularJS website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), I just added the clear button.

Comment: bro but i am not using text area i am using editable div

Comment: @RashidHussain Why are you doing that? Editable divs are only used in really special cases. I update my answer with a contenteditable div.

Comment: bro i have this project when mostly things was done in it and i am just a worker i cant change code

Comment: @RashidHussain Okay, I understand. Did you try my updated example?

Comment: i tried but on `ng-click=""` i have already function running called comment like this: `ng-click="comment(<?php echo $itemId ?>,<?php echo $itemDesc ?>  ,user_comment,0,0,mood)"`

Comment: how can i use 2 function at 1 ng-click?

Comment: @RashidHussain You can chain call functions like this: ng-click="function(); function2();"

Comment: i tried like this `<input  type="button"   value="POST" ng-click="comment(<?php echo $itemId ?>,<?php echo $itemDesc ?>  ,user_comment,0,0,mood);userContent='';">` but not working

Comment: @RashidHussain Make sure that you have added the directive correctly by putting a console.log("test") or something in this event: element.on('blur keyup change', function(){scope.$evalAsync(read);}); Edit: Also make sure that you have bound an ng-model to the div.

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for me, here the
html code

```
`<textarea  [(ngModel)] ="myInput"></textarea>
 <button (click) = "this.deleteText();">clear</button>`
```

angular code

```
myInput: string;

deleteText(){  
  this.myInput = '';   
}
```